# How to change key to 'accept' intellisense 'offer' for VB.Net in Visual Studio 2015 (update 3)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, intellisense

When I'm coding in VB.Net in VS2015 I would like to use CTRL+SPACE to select Intellisense proposal when coding. Currently I have to use SHIFT+SPACE and I see no way to change it.

[image: VB.Net code editing]

In the preceeding example screenshot it is visible that I have 3 potential options to autocomplete. I can select any of them with key up/down but in order to select the proposal I have following options:

- Press 'SHIFT+SPACE' - this will accept the proposal and position the
  carret right after the word enabling me to press '(' or whatever else
  I want
- Press 'SPACE' - this will accept the proposal but it will also
  add a white space at the end which is ok for properties/fields but
  not good for methods
- Press '(' - this will accept the proposal but it
  will also add a '(' character at thend which is ok for functions/sub
  but not good for properies/fields
- Press 'CTRL+SPACE' - this actually does not do anything :(, CTRL on its own makes the Intellisense menu gray-out

In the key configuration window I found the Edit.CompleteWord command:

[image: Keyboard binding dialog]

However this command already has CTRL+SPACE assigned it but it simply does not work. In addition SHIFT+SPACE is not mentioned as one of the keybindings.

Note:
VS2015 does have a flag 'Toggle Completion Mode' but I actually see no difference if this option is checked or not.

Comment: You can use tab, which doesn't append anything to the selected option. Enter is another options but will append a newline. And Ctrl+Space brings up the intellisense options but doesn't complete them, so it might be overriding the compelete option?.

Comment: Have you any other program running in backgroud which might listen to `Ctr+Space` already?

Comment: @Alex Not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

you can Use Tab and this will accept the proposal and position the current right after Tab Use space it well show You next Complete Word .